# Howto simplify css rule with multiple class selectors for multiple elements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is it possible to simplify the following css rule so that I do not have to duplicate the class selector `.simpleTable.cellBorders` for all elements (td and th)?

```css
.simpleTable.cellBorders td, .simpleTable.cellBorders th {
    border: 1px #ccc solid;
}
```

The idea is that td and th cells have a border if the table has the classes `simpleTable` and `cellBorders` assigned like:

```html
<table class="simpleTable cellBorders">
    <tr><th>My Header</th> ... </tr>
    <tr><td>Some cell</td> ... </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If i understand your question, why not just do .simpleTable tr, .simpleTable tr th { /*** your code ****/}

Comment: CSS4 allows you to do like this `.simpleTable.cellBorders :-webkit-any(td, th) {}`. http://jsfiddle.net/ygKj9/. Mozilla also supports it. IE not.

Comment: @dfsq: The :-webkit-any selector will be called :matches() in CSS4. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can certainly use the universal selector (*) together with the child selector (>), as there is no other valid element besides `th` and `td` that could be inside a `tr`:

```
.simpleTable.cellBorders tr>* {
    border: 1px #ccc solid;
}
```

Note that putting another child selector between `.simpleTable.cellBorders`and `tr` will not work as expected, as browsers (at least Firefox) will add a `tbody` element between the `table` element and its `tr` elements, as defined by the [HTML 4.01 standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3) as well as the [HTML5 standard](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/tabular-data.html#the-tbody-element):

> Tag omission in text/html:
>       A tbody element's start tag can be omitted if the first thing inside the tbody element is a tr element, and if the element is not
>   immediately preceded by a tbody, thead, or tfoot element whose end tag
>   has been omitted. (It can't be omitted if the element is empty.)

Answer (score -1):

look this :

```
.simpleTable tr > *{
    border: 1px #ccc solid;
}
```